# Recreate Wikipedia list of states by GDP with SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to recreate this list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States_by_GDP

with a Wikidata SPARQL query.

I can find states by population [with this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fstate%20%3FstateLabel%20%3Fpopulation%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fstate%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ35657%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fstate%20%3Fpopulation%20%3FstateLabel%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fpopulation%29)

Additionally, the fields:

- population (P1082)
- GDP (P2131)
- And some extra ones, like unemployment (P1198)

are covered by the [wikiproject economics](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Economics), though only at the country level.

That said, seeing the "List of states and territories of the United States by GDP" article makes me think at least P2131 may be available at the state level.

I have [tried the following query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fstate%20%3FstateLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fgdp%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fstate%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ35657%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP2131%20%3Fgdp%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fstate%20%3Fpopulation%20%3FstateLabel%20%3Fgdp%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fpopulation%29).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?state ?stateLabel ?population ?gdp
{
  ?state wdt:P31 wd:Q35657 ;
         wdt:P1082 ?population ;
         wdt:P2131 ?gdp ;
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
GROUP BY ?state ?population ?stateLabel ?gdp
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
```

And see no matches.  What's the right query for this?

(Point in time for a given year would be excellent, like how the table gives me 2019, 2020, etc., but I'll settle for learning the vanilla first.)

Comment: Ehm, just take a look at one of the items resulting in your first query (e.g. [Q99](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q99)) and you'll see that they make no use of property P2131.

Comment: For the rest, your query seems correct to me. If you wish, I could upload the WP article's data on Wikidata via bot.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this, @horcrux.  It would be interesting to try auto-botting the project lists at least.

Comment: I don't know anything about wikidata bots, but seems very neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of a Wikidata internal convention, I had to upload the GPD data in the items about the States' economies, that are linked through property [P8744](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P8744).

E.g., for the State of [Maine](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q724) you'll find the data in [economy of Maine](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q60850384).

This is the correct query for obtaining what you want ([test](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fstate%20%3FstateLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fgdp%20%28year%28%3Fdate%29%20as%20%3Fyear%29%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fstate%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ35657%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP8744%2Fwdt%3AP2131%20%3Fgdp%20.%0A%20%20%3FgdpStmt%20ps%3AP2131%20%3Fgdp%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fdate%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fstate%20%3Fpopulation%20%3FstateLabel%20%3Fgdp%20%3Fdate%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fyear%29%20DESC%28%3Fpopulation%29%0A)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?state ?stateLabel ?population ?gdp (year(?date) as ?year)
{
  ?state wdt:P31 wd:Q35657 ;
         wdt:P1082 ?population ;
         wdt:P8744/wdt:P2131 ?gdp .
  ?gdpStmt ps:P2131 ?gdp ;
           pq:P585 ?date .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
GROUP BY ?state ?population ?stateLabel ?gdp ?date
ORDER BY DESC(?year) DESC(?population)
```

It also considers grouping by year.

Comment: This is awesome.  Can I ask one thing, is the population clause also aligned with the year used for the gdp?

Comment: Nope, because the single items do not have a population updated to 2019 or 2020.